# Building an array of T NxM matrices where one item in each matrix changes

Tags: list-manipulation, tensors, partitions, iteration

As I do not use Mathematica often enough, I am a bit rusty. I need to work on an array of T matrices and each of those NxM matrices has the following pattern:
$$
   \begin{equation}
    A(t):=
\left(
  \begin{array}{cccc}
     \alpha_1(t) +\beta(t) +\bar{\beta}(t) & \beta(t)+\bar{\beta}(t) & ... & \beta(t)+\bar{\beta}(t) \\
     \beta(t)+\bar{\beta}(t) & {\alpha}_2(t) +\beta(t)+ \bar{\beta}(t) & ... & \beta(t)+\bar{\beta}(t) \\ 
     {}\vdots{}      & {}\vdots{} & {}\ddots{} & {}\vdots{} \\
     \beta(t)+\bar{\beta}(t) & \beta(t)+\bar{\beta}(t) & ... & \alpha_N(t)+\beta(t)+\bar{\beta}(t)
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}
$$
where the $\alpha_1(t)$,$\beta(t)$ and $\bar{\beta}$  are vectors of size $T$. As can be seen, in each matrix only the diagonal changes as the $\alpha_i(t)$ are added, with  $i \in {1,N}$, and $t \in {[1,T]}$.
I am sure that the solution must be reasonably easy, but not for me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, you can add a diagonal matrix to a constant matrix:

```
ClearAll[a, b, bb];

{n, m, T} = {3, 2, 3};
A = Table[
  ConstantArray[
    Indexed[b, t] + Indexed[bb, t], {n, m}]
   + SparseArray[
    {{i_, i_} -> Indexed[a, {i, t}]}, {n, m}], {t, T}]

MatrixForm /@ A // MatrixForm
```

where, as you mention, `a` ($\alpha$) is a `n*T` tensor, `b` ($\beta$) and `bb` ($\bar{\beta}$) are vectors of size `T`. For instance,

```
a = RandomReal[1, {n, T}];
b = RandomReal[1, T];
bb = RandomReal[1, T];
MatrixForm /@ A // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Perhaps accessing the elements of `a`, `b` and `bb` should better be done with `Part` since OP claims they are "vectors".

Comment: @Natas Thanks for advice! I thought that would make the code a bit messy though...

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer, satisifes my need completely. It saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @Xavier: You're welcome. Great if it helps.